# Trying to put a three.js OBJLoader into a HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

So my problem is simple: I tried to link a three.js script with a html canvas. But I failed, and I really don't know how to do this. Here is my code (I already loaded necessary scripts in my HTML head) :`

```
  window.onload = function() {
var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer;

var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX;
var windowHalfY;

init();
animate();


function init() {

    container = document.getElementById('mon_canvas');

            width = container.width;
            height = container.height;
            alert("Width :"+width+",Height :"+height);

           windowHalfX=width/2;
           windowHalfY=height/2;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 300;

            // On ajoute les controles
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    // scene

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
    scene.add( ambient );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
    directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    // model

    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load( './three/obj/male02/male02.obj', './three/obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( object ) {
        object.position.y = - 80;
        scene.add( object );
    } );
    //

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

    function onWindowResize() {
           windowHalfX = width / 2;
    windowHalfY = height / 2;

    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    render();
}

function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();

}

function render() {
          // camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    stats.update();

}
  }
```

`

and what I have in my HTML body code : 
`<canvas style="border: dashed 1px black;margin-left: 25%;" id="mon_canvas" width="500" height="500"> 
         Sorry, no Webgl for you, IE user :c.
      </canvas>`

I really don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using canvas tags try using div instead. I have no luck placing three.js objects into a canvas directly. The library puts a canvas in the div anyway, so I never use canvas tags when using three.js.

```
<div style="border: dashed 1px black;margin-left: 25%;" id="mon_canvas" width="500" height="500"> Sorry, no Webgl for you, IE user :c. </div>
```

Also, if you using chrome, use the developer tools to make sure that the obj and any images are being loaded from the correct location. Depending on how you exported the obj file, the MTL file might be using absolute file locations instead of relative.